# Terminal has different Python version in PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, directory, pycharm

My current Python version is 3.8, but I do also have python 3.6 installed in another directory. My IDE is PyCharm. I set up a new project using version 3.6 so I can use an older version of Tensorflow, namely Tensorflow==2.0.0b1. However, when using pip install on this project it still recognizes version 3.8. My question is how can I pip install to my my 3.6 directory and not the 3.8 site packages folder.

Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\my_folder_name\PycharmProjects\Anomaly_Dectection>pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 21.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I need the pip install to go here:

```
C:\Users\folder_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages
```

P.S: I set up a venv with Python 3.6 for this new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, when you run pip from the script folder:

```
C:\Users\folder_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
```

If there is no pip3 in your current directory, windows is looking at your PATH variable and i guess, it takes pip3 from the newest python, not 3.6.